# php:uploading a file on server

Tags: php, file, upload, file-upload

I am using the following code to upload the file on my server.
How do I store it in a particular folder?

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use '`move_uploaded_file`'

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "$uploads_dir/$name");
```

'`$uploads_dir`' holds the folder you want to store the uploaded file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$src = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$dest = '/your/favorite/path/myfile.jpg';
move_uploaded_file($src,$dest);
```

Obviously, you'll want to do some basic error checking - make sure the destination directory is writable, handle any exceptions that may occur, etc.  That's the basic idea, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a decent article on the topic.

[secure file upload check list](http://hungred.com/2009/08/17/useful-information/secure-file-upload-check-list-php/)

Comment: Very Good Article about security. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

The file will be stored in a default folder, and then you [move_uploaded_file](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to the desired folder.